# Не загружается активити в котором очень много расчетов!

Tags: android, java, activity

У меня приложение состоит из кучи активити которые нормально работают. 
Есть последний класс в котором производится расчет кучи переменных, их сортировка - массив из 108 элементов в каждом из которых по 5 переменных! И еще парсинг и вывод результатов!
Суть в том что при отладке на эмуляторе все отлично работает, но как только я скидываю на устройство все так же работает кроме последнего активити в котором производится расчеты!
С чем это может быть связано? Может не хватает ресурсов для расчета? Помогите разобраться! Работа горит. Думал что сделал проверяя все на эмуляторе, скинул заказчику он проверил на трех разных девайсах ни на одном из них последнее активити не запускается!(((

Comment: нужно смотреть лог. Без него ничего не можно придумать. Но так, на вскидку, есть три варианта.

 - происходит банальное деление на ноль или что то подобное (или строку символов пытаются к числу преобразовать, там только одни буквы)
 - весь код выполняется долго, достаточно долго (больше 3-5 секунд) и он выполняется в главном потоке. И система прибивает процесс.
 - устройства у заказчика достаточно старые, а Вы применяете апи более поздних версий. Классика жанра - метод `isEmpty` у типа `String` доступен только с 2.3 и выше.

Comment: Логирование веду на эмуляторе все работает отлично! 
Все расчеты isBack. Из эмпти нигде не использую! У них какая то моторола рейзер API17

Comment: советую все расчеты вынести из основного потока, это будет при любом раскладе правильно, а в основном лучше показать прогресс загрузки или что-то вроде этого

Comment: Сейчас попробую! А почему так критично? И почему сволочь андроид так медленно считает?)

Comment: И еще если имеются java сурипты то они наверное еще больше съедают?

Comment: андроид считает очень быстро. На некоторых тестах (преобразования yuv->rgb) 7 нексус обходил The New iPad как лежачего (на андроиде примерялось ndk).

А что такое "сурипты"?

Comment: *скрипт
смог добавить!))

Comment: это не критично, просто не очень красиво проводить длительные вычисления(более 1с) в основном потоке, потому что программа подвисает и пользователь остается в недоумении и грешит на телефон :)
лучше лишний раз показать прогресс :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Попробуйте вынести расчеты в отдельный поток. Как вариант можно наследовать класс от AsyncTask и после сортировки вернуть результат в главный поток (только в нём можно работать с View). Думаю, сейчас ошибка именно в большой задержке.